# List with 400 items + images

Tags: ios, image, list, uitableview

What is the correct way for building a scrollable list with images
that will be able to deal with 400 items?
Should I use `UITableView` for these?

What is the correct way for storing and retrieving the data? SQlite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITablebview can display an arbitrarily large list because it only has to reserve memory to display the rows that are actually on screen. An indexed table can let your users jump down the list.

Core data would be your best option to store your data in.

Comment: If one of these answers solves your issue, you should select the checkmark next to one of them so that the system knows it has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely UITableView, and SQLite would work, but CoreData would be better.